# Каким образом из последовательности байт собрать excel файл с помощью Ruby

Tags: ruby

В БД MySQL с помощью C# записывается произвольный Excel файл в двоичном виде (то есть как строка байт, разделенная пробелами), которую мне необходимо собрать обратно в файл с помощью Ruby. При попытке побайтно восстановить файл у меня в этот файл записывается массив, а не восстанавливается сам файл.

```
byte_arr_1 = byte_arr.split(" ")

output_file = File.open("3_carrier.xlsx", "a")
  for i in 0..(byte_arr_1.length - 1)
    output_file.syswrite(byte_arr_1[i].to_i)
  end
output_file.close
```

Comment: Поясните, что Вы имеете в виду под _"файл в двоичном виде (то есть как строка байт, разделенная пробелами)"_? Потому что первая часть этого выражения противоречит второй (той, что в скобках)

Comment: [1010000 1001011 11 100 10100 0 110 0 1000 0 0 ] - часть строки из БД, куда записан файл. Я немного некорректно выразился изначально, это именно строка из байт. Из которой необходимо собрать файл.

Comment: Это больше похоже на строку из бит, а не из байт. Если так, тогда каждый элемент `byte_arr_1` надо еще предварительно распарсить как двоичное представление числа (не знаю уж, какая функция в ruby за это отвечает). А вообще, Вам бы стоило намекнуть тому человеку, который придумал хранить файлы в базе в таком виде, что это не очень здравая идея. :)

Comment: Ну с хранением выбирать особо не приходится...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
byte_arr_1 = byte_arr.split " "

File.new("3_carrier.xlsx", "wb") do |file|
  byte_arr_1.each do |byte|
    file.putc byte.to_i 2
  end
end
```